# Resize and include Animated PNG in Android drawable

Tags: android

I have this animated picture that I would like to include in my apps:

http://www.smogon.com/download/sprites/bw/184.png

Please let me know if there is any available tool to resize the picture (for different drawable folders) and if there is any memory risk when running apps using animated png.

I have been using this website http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example but apparently it doesn't work out.

Edit: also, since `ImageView` no longer has `android:layout_weight` as an attribute, if I want to specify the percentage of screen to scale my image into, which attribute should I use? Say for example I want the image's height to be rescaled to 40% of the screen.

Comment: there is no such thing like animated png, there is animated gif however

Comment: oh my bad. What is that png file called then? The image kinda moves around

Comment: That is merely a mislabeled animated GIF. If you right click the image and press View Image Info (on Firefox), it'll tell you the file type.